# UICollectionView screen-sized cell rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Imagine a composition like this -> 
UIViewController with root view containing these subviews :
- header view pinned to top, 
- footer view pinned to bottom,
- scrollview matching the screen bounds with uiimageview as content where the image of the image view is a landscape image  and the imageview size is aspect fitting the scrollview, zommscale is 1.
If I rotate this controller, thanks to proper layout(doesnt matter if manual or autolayout) the resulting animation to new landscape screen bounds is flawless.

If I put this controller as a member of UIPageViewController multiple times (effectively creating a gallery) the rotation of any particular page, containing a controller from above is also flawless.

In both cases above, none of the layers dissapear, the resizing animation nicely comforms to layout rules. The animation as a whole makes complete sense.

Now let's create a Collection controller with a horizontal flow layout. Zero insets, zero interitem size, and the cell size matching one screen. We ended up with horizontal gallery right?

So why, when I rotate the device, is the final animation composition so messy? 
I slowed down the animation and what I see is views from neighbouring controllers temporarily "leaking in" 
the central image view is deformed while animated and eventually thrown away, and finaly it calms down and a new! cell content is shown with proper layout that comforms the landscape device orientation. It's like those views are not sure what they want and behave like drunk.

Why cant the collection view rotate in such a way that only the cell will resize alongside the animation coordinator and firmly keep it's center in the center of screen?

How to force collection view to resize it's current and only visible cell in same manner as if it was a root view?

Comment: Can you attached a video of such behavior? Or a sample github project?

Comment: Is your problem only with the orientation animation? or the final layout is messy?

Comment: the final layout is fine...but thr animation is messy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate a UICollectionView similar to the photos app and keep the current view centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708407/how-to-rotate-a-uicollectionview-similar-to-the-photos-app-and-keep-the-current)