# UICollectionViewFlowLayout `targetContentOffset` - how to keep cells centered after orientation change?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) that centers each cell. To do this, I overrode [`targetContentOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617724-targetcontentoffset), which the collection view calls whenever the user lifts up their finger. However, once I rotate the device, the cells get off center — `targetContentOffset` is not called.

| Normally, cells are centered | After rotating the device, cells are no longer centered |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Swiping on cells centers each cell] | [image: Rotating the devices makes the cells get off center. But as soon as you swipe, they snap back.] |

**Note 1:** After rotating, just swipe a bit on the cells, and they bounce back to center...
**Note 2:** This gets printed in my console:

```
2021-11-16 21:37:54.979021-0800 TargetContentOffsetTest[30817:356789] [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x12f02d400 Disabling recursion trigger logging
```

Here's my code ([demo repo](https://github.com/aheze/TargetContentOffsetTest)):

```
class PagingFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]() /// custom attributes
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero /// the scrollable content size of the collection view
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize { return contentSize } /// pass scrollable content size back to the collection view
    
    /// pass attributes to the collection view flow layout
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? { return layoutAttributes[indexPath.item] }
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? { return layoutAttributes.filter { rect.intersects($0.frame) } }
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        let cellWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let cellHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
        
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        var currentCellOrigin = CGFloat(0) /// used for each cell's origin
        
        for index in 0..<3 { /// hardcoded, but only for now
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: currentCellOrigin, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            currentCellOrigin += cellWidth
        }
        
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: currentCellOrigin, height: cellHeight)
        self.layoutAttributes = layoutAttributes
    }
    
    /// center the cell
    /// this is called when the finger lifts, but NOT when the device rotates!
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let contentOffset = collectionView?.contentOffset.x ?? 0
        let closestPoint = layoutAttributes.min { abs($0.frame.origin.x - contentOffset) < abs($1.frame.origin.x - contentOffset) }
        return closestPoint?.frame.origin ?? proposedContentOffset
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let flowLayout = PagingFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
        ])
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 3 }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _ = collectionView /// setup
    }
}
```

How can I make the collection view call `targetContentOffset` after a bounds change/rotation event? What is the correct way to ensure my cells always stay centered — is there something automatic I can use, or should I subscribe to [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) back in my view controller and manually call [`setContentOffset(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset)?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just setting `isPagingAvailable = true` on the collection view to get this same behavior?

Comment: @AdamPro13 good point. In this case `isPagingEnabled` would probably work, but eventually I'd like to have some more precise control... for example, taking content inset and spacing into account. And my cells most likely won't take up the width of the entire screen.

Comment: you could add two methods (link below) in your ```PagingFlowLayout```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868999/11332605

Comment: or you could just do in your ```viewWillTransition```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322706/11332605

Comment: @Jokecoder thanks for the links! I tried the first one, but `targetContentOffset` still doesn't get called. I'll try the second one.

Comment: Ok, the second one works. The animation is a bit weird, though... but good enough for now.

Comment: @aheze really? I played around with the project and it was working fine for me (at least the collection layout was resizing after layout change)
Update: oh, I deleted the project, I am downloading it and trying again, will share the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the method is getting called not when you just rotate the device, but when the layout changes. Meaning, if you change from `Landscape Left` to `Landscape Right` the delegate method is not called — however if you rotating from any `Landscape` to `Portrait` or other way around, it is working fine.

### Important!

For maintaining the centered collection view cell, add the [`targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617724-targetcontentoffset) method. This is called after a rotation, and is **not** the same as your current [`targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617729-targetcontentoffset) method. In your final code, you should use **both** of these methods. To summarize:

- `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:)` is called after a layout change
- `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)` is called when the user lifts their finger

So, in your `PagingFlowLayout` class, paste the following code:

```
private var focusedIndexPath: IndexPath?

override func prepare(forAnimatedBoundsChange oldBounds: CGRect) {
    super.prepare(forAnimatedBoundsChange: oldBounds)
    focusedIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first
}
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    guard
        let indexPath = focusedIndexPath,
        let attributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath),
        let collectionView = collectionView
    else {
        return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset)
    }
    return CGPoint(
        x: attributes.frame.origin.x - collectionView.contentInset.left,
        y: attributes.frame.origin.y - collectionView.contentInset.top
    )
}
override func finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange() {
    super.finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange()
    focusedIndexPath = nil
}
```

The code was from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868999/11332605.